# Prove that $\mathrm{Hom}_\Bbb Z(\Bbb Q,C) = 0$ for any cyclic group $C$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that $\mathrm{Hom}_\Bbb Z(\Bbb Q,C)  = 0$ for any cyclic group $C$.

In order to prove this I need to show that any $\Bbb Z$-linear homomorphism $f : \Bbb Q \to C$ is the trivial one. If we denote $C = \langle c\rangle$, then each element of $C$ is some power of $c$.

I'm trying to find a contradiction by supposing that $f(1)=c^m$ for $m \in \Bbb Z$. Now because $$q\cdot f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = f(p) = pf(1) = pc^m$$ we have that $c^m = \frac{q}{p}$, but I feel like this is nonsense since why would $c^m$ need to be a rational number at all?

It is true that if $C$ is finite, then it is isomorphic to some $\Bbb Z_m$ so is there a reason to consider two cases here?

Comment: You're mixing additive and multiplicative notation. The element you are writing as $pc^m$ should either be denoted as $(pm) c$ or $c^{pm}$.

Comment: Why do you need $c^m$ to be a rational number?  It's an element of the abstract group $C$.  I don't see how you deduce $c^m=q/p$.

Comment: Your strategy to approach this by contradiction doesn't make sense. If $f : \mathbb{Q} \to C$ is a homomorphism, then $f(1)$ *will* be equal to $mc$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. You will not be able to contradict this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think people whould try to wean themselves off trying to prove everything "by contradiction." There's nothing wrong per se about proofs by contradiction, but the over-reliance on always trying to use a proof by contradiction often results in unnecessarily overwrought or twisty arguments. The nice thing about direct proofs is that you know *exactly* what you are going for. In a proof by contradiction, you are often flailing around spraying statements hoping you will somehow be able to spot a contradiction *somewhere*...

If $C$ is cyclic of order $m$, then for any $x\in C$ we have $x^m=e$ (using multiplicative notation). Now, let $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to C$ be a group morphism. Note that because the domain is additive but the codomain is multiplicative, this means
$$f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$$
and for all integers $m$, $f(ma) = f(a)^m$.

For any $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, we know that $\frac{a}{m}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then
$$f(a) = f\left(m\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)\right) = f\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^m = e,$$
because, whatever $f(\frac{a}{m})$ is, it is an element of $C$ and therefore taking an $m$th power of it will give the identity element. So $f(a)=e$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$.

If $C$ is infinite cyclic, on the other hand, with generator $x$, then consider $f(1)=x^a$. Then we must have that for all $n\gt 0$,
$$x^a = f(1) = f\left(n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$
Now, if $f(\frac{1}{n})=x^{b_n}$, then this gives $x^a = (x^{b_n})^n = x^{nb_n}$.

In an infinite cyclic group, $x^a=x^b$ holds if and only if $a=b$, so we have that $a=nb_n$; that means that $a$ is divisible by all positive integers, and therefore that $a=0$. Thus, $f(1)=e$, and therefore $f(\frac{1}{n})=e$, since $nb_n=0$, so $b_n=0$. Thus,
$$f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^a = e^a = e.$$
So $f$ sends everything to $e$.

Note that what the argument uses is the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is *divisible*: that for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and all positive integers $n$, there exists a $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $ny=x$. So the arguments can be adapted to show that if $D$ is any divisible group, and $C$ is cyclic, then $\mathrm{Hom}(D,C)$ is trivial.

Comment: $C$ may be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start! You're right that saying $c^m = q/p$ is nonsense (I think you really you mean $c^m = q/p \cdot f(p/q)$, but this also does not make sense). However, the equation $q \cdot f(p/q) = pc^m$ that you *did* derive is actually true! This is bad notation though; you're mixing additive notation ($p x = x + \cdots + x$) with multiplicative notation ($c^m = c \cdots c$), but there is only one group operation in play! I'll stick to additive notation because we're thinking about $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

As a special case of your identity, we have $n f(1/n) = mc$ for all positive integers $n$. Can you find a reason that this implies $mc = 0$ in any cyclic group? Then, what else is needed to complete the proof?

As you suggest, it might be helpful to consider the finite and infinite cyclic groups as separate cases.